# texstudio problems with language tools

Tags: latex

I have already asked in the forum of LanguageTools but the said it seems to be a problem of Texstudio which does not send the language parameter to the server. Do you have an idea what might be the problem.
I am using Linux mint 17.2, Java 8 and TexStudio 2.6.6
Stacktrace from the server:

```
2016-05-13 11:38:08 An error has occurred. Access from 127.0.0.1, text length 14. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '<none>' is not a language code known to LanguageTool. Supported language codes are: ast-ES, be-BY, br-FR, ca-ES, ca-ES-valencia, da-DK, de, de-AT, de-CH, de-DE, de-DE-x-simple-language, el-GR, en, en-AU, en-CA, en-GB, en-NZ, en-US, en-ZA, eo, es, fa, fr, gl-ES, is-IS, it, ja-JP, km-KH, lt-LT, ml-IN, nl, pl-PL, pt, pt-BR, pt-PT, ro-RO, ru-RU, sk-SK, sl-SI, sv, ta-IN, tl-PH, uk-UA, xx-XX, zh-CN. The list of languages is read from META-INF/org/languagetool/language-module.properties in the Java classpath. See http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api for details.
    at org.languagetool.Languages.getLanguageForShortName(Languages.java:153)
    at org.languagetool.server.LanguageToolHttpHandler.getLanguage(LanguageToolHttpHandler.java:488)
    at org.languagetool.server.LanguageToolHttpHandler.checkText(LanguageToolHttpHandler.java:382)
    at org.languagetool.server.LanguageToolHttpHandler.handle(LanguageToolHttpHandler.java:209)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-13 11:38:08 An error has occurred. Access from 127.0.0.1, text length 16. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '<none>' is not a language code known to LanguageTool. Supported language codes are: ast-ES, be-BY, br-FR, ca-ES, ca-ES-valencia, da-DK, de, de-AT, de-CH, de-DE, de-DE-x-simple-language, el-GR, en, en-AU, en-CA, en-GB, en-NZ, en-US, en-ZA, eo, es, fa, fr, gl-ES, is-IS, it, ja-JP, km-KH, lt-LT, ml-IN, nl, pl-PL, pt, pt-BR, pt-PT, ro-RO, ru-RU, sk-SK, sl-SI, sv, ta-IN, tl-PH, uk-UA, xx-XX, zh-CN. The list of languages is read from META-INF/org/languagetool/language-module.properties in the Java classpath. See http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api for details.
    at org.languagetool.Languages.getLanguageForShortName(Languages.java:153)
    at org.languagetool.server.LanguageToolHttpHandler.getLanguage(LanguageToolHttpHandler.java:488)
    at org.languagetool.server.LanguageToolHttpHandler.checkText(LanguageToolHttpHandler.java:382)
    at org.languagetool.server.LanguageToolHttpHandler.handle(LanguageToolHttpHandler.java:209)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I could solve it. The problem was, I used version 2.6.6 from package manager. Using version 2.10 from texstuido.org solved this issue.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem in v 2.10.8 running on Linux Mint 18